# Mapping multiples tables with same schema to same pojo class

Tags: hibernate

I hava a pojo class in which I am using Hibernate annotation.
In my database I have two tables with **similiar schema.**
I want to know whether there is any way in hibernate annotation so that **same pojo class can be used for these two tables**.
Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: If you add an annotation, it will become an entity and won't be a POJO anymore. How Hibernate then can find out on which database it should save the entity if it has 2 mappings? I think it is not possible and mostly not a good idea.

Comment: but if I have two similiar tables one of workflow and one main schema then do I need to create separate pojo classes for each of them

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are similar but unrelated then you probably want to use @MappedSuperclass.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses

This will allow you to declare the common mappings in the @MappedSuperclass and your concrete Entity classes can extend from this.